# TLS Handshake fails when trying to connect to a remote server from certain network

Tags: ssl, https, connection, vpn, tls1.2

When trying to connect to our servers webinterfaces via vpn, from my homenetwork, instead of getting the expected `Server Hello, Certificate` TLS package, this package seems to get lost every time.

After getting redirected to port 443, my machine sends its `Client Hello` packages.
in Wireshark I then get the Info `[TCP Previous segment not captured], Continuation Data` ( which is reportedly a SSL package... )
Then there are a couple of TCP packages, requesting missing data, but then it just stops, and I get a `ERR_TIMED_OUT` in the Browser.

The Version used is TLSv1.2
Everything else over this connection seems to work fine
The https certificates are self-signed

This problem occurs on all machines in my network.
This problem doesn't occur on my coworkers machines in their networks, ( although with same VPN ).
This problem doesn't occur, when I'M using another VPN (from my network) (it's for another purpose).
This problem occurs on all Servers in the Network

I turned off my firewall,
searched for any open https ports on my device,
looked for overlaying ip addresses,
used multiple devices to try to connect

probably someone has an idea what I could do,
thanks in advance